# Electrical power for brick BBQ. GFCI outlet constantly tripping

Tags: wiring, gfci

Electrical power for exterior brick BBQ plugs. GFCI outlet constantly tripping. The GFCI has two sub-outlets. There are three item plugged in:

1. Fountain Water Pump with cord running in ground
2. BBQ rotisserie motor
3. A low voltage transformer timer for yard lighting.

I have replaced the transformer, the rotisserie motor and the GFCI outlet. the results continue to be the same. Ideas?

Comment: What happens if you unplug everything? If this solves the problem, try plugging these back in one at a time.

Comment: Yes, stop throwing parts at it and diagnose.  You need to disconnect things until the GFCI trips stop.

Comment: Or disconnect everything and reconnect 1 at a time giving sufficient time between each re-connection for the fault to show. There is no substitute for a logical approach.

Comment: Does it stop tripping when you disconnect the water pump?

Comment: I missed the pump had not been replaced. But the GFCI had + 3phase.  The boxes could also have water in them causing the problems.

Comment: Also keep in mind you must disconnect both hot and neutral.  If neutral is still connected, it CAN trip the GFCI.